# Dockerization Failing, during application Build

Tags: java, mysql, docker, dockerfile

I'm new in Stack overflow. I have a several issues while building Spring Boot Application, PetClinic. I have created a Dockerfile with Multi Stage build, but I also want to a connect to MySQL Database. I have read a lot of documentation how to Dockerize the PetClinic App, but my case seems for me is different, and related solutions are not relevant. I'm dockerizing a https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic

So could you please suggest me, how to:

1. Create a Docker Image with PetClinic Application
2. Connect a created docker image of PetClinic Application to MySQL Data Base
3. How to set up volumes between, MySQL and PetClinic Application

**Here is my Dockerfile**

```
# Multi Stage Build > Step 1 Clone > Base Image Alpine Git
FROM alpine/git as get
ARG  url
WORKDIR  /app
RUN  git clone ${url}

# Multi Stage Build > Step 2 Compile > Base Image Alpine Maven
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine as compile
ARG  project
# ENV  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE docker, mysql
WORKDIR  /app
COPY --from=get /app/${project} /app
RUN  mvn package

# Multi Stage Build > Step 3 Build > Base Image Alpine Openjdk
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ARG  artifactid
ARG  version
ENV  artifact ${artifactid}-${version}.jar
WORKDIR  /app
COPY --from=compile /app/target/${artifact} /app
EXPOSE   8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c" ]
CMD  [ "java -jar ${artifact}" ]
```

As you noticed I've commented line with `# ENV  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE docker, mysql`

So this line as I understand from https://gitlab.comquent.de/petclinic/spring-petclinic-microservices/tree/master
Need to be set as env variable to communicate with MySQL Data Base, however if this variable is set, the maven can not build the Docker Image, and complaining that:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException:
Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException:
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException:
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I'm not good at Java, but the issues is answering for it self:

If set `ENV  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE docker, mysql` it is not building an image

If not set `ENV  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE docker, mysql` it is building an image

**Here is Docker-Compose file, to build MySQL Data Base**

```
---
 version: '3'
 services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
     environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=petclinic
       - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
       - MYSQL_USER=petclinic
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=petclinic
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=petclinic
     volumes:
       - "./conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d:rw"
       - "./conf.d/data:/var/lib/mysql"
   spring:
     image: local-petclinic:latest
     ports:
       - "8080:8080"
     environment:
       - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker,mysql
     depends_on:
       - mysql
```

**Here is the Image Build parameters (I build image first, and that run compose)**

```
docker build \
   --build-arg url=https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git \
   --build-arg project=spring-petclinic     \
   --build-arg artifactid=spring-petclinic  \
   --build-arg version=2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT \
   -t local-petclinic:latest - < Dockerfile
```

Comment: An image build can't communicate with other Docker services, even if they're in the same `docker-compose.yml` file.  But it seems a little unusual to need access to your database to build a jar file.  What part of your build needs the database connectivity; can you remove that?

Comment: Here is not the point to connect the Data Base, while building a Docker Image, consider that Docker Image is has been build, but than the Docker Image should connect to Data Base. If you look carefully you will notice that, ``docker-compose.yaml`` already consist a build ready Docker Image